# Copying Postgres 12 database to another server with smallest downtime

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, master-slave, master-master

I'm going to migrate a production PostgreSQL 12 database (~200GB) to another more powerful server. There are a bunch of partitioned tables, some without primary key (theoretically, it won't be a problem to temporarily add them if needed).

Is there any solution to migrate without or at least with the smallest downtime?

Comment: Use replication, that reduces the downtime to almost zero

Comment: @FrankHeikens I can't get the following. As long initial copying will be in progress, as much data shift will be. How standby server will make up it after initial copying will finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FrankHeikens wrote in the comment to the question, we need to configure master-standby replication.

Here are steps on master (**Postgres 12**):

**NOTE:** All commands run on behalf of a user with sudo permissions.

1. Create Postgres user for replication

```
psql -U postgres
CREATE ROLE replication WITH REPLICATION PASSWORD 'REPLICATION_USER_PASSWORD' LOGIN;
```

2. Add replication user to pg_hba.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
# Add the following line
> To Existing Server
host    replication     replication     STANDBY_SERVER_IP/32       md5
```

3. Enable replication.

**NOTE**: *wal_keep_segments* should be as much enough to keep *wal* files while base backup is in progress.

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgres.conf
# Uncomment and edit values
listen_addresses = '*' 
wal_level = replica 
wal_keep_segments = 256   # (each segment is 16 MB by default, so ~5GB of free space is need  **for our case**)
max_wal_senders = 2 # (for case of single standby)
max_replication_slots = 2 # (for case of single standby)
hot_standby = on
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

4. Open Postgres network port (5432 by default) in a system firewall.
5. Restart Posgtres

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Here are steps on standby (**Postgres 12**):

**NOTE:** All commands run on behalf of a user with sudo permissions.

1. . Stop Posgtres

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

2. Clean up data and logs directories.

```
sudo rm /var/log/postgresql/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/*
# Ensure that cleaning up is none
sudo du -sh /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/
```

2. Enable replication.

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgres.conf
# Uncomment and edit values
hot_standby = on
primary_conninfo = 'user=replication password=<REPLICATION_USER_PASSWORD> host=MASTER_SERVER_IP port=5432'
```

3. Enable Postgres standby mode.

```
cd /etc/postgresql/12/main/
sudo touch standby.signal
sudo chown postgres:postgres standby.signal
```

4. Create base backup.

```
# Enter 2 passwords: for local 'postgres' user and then for remote 'replication' user
su - postgres -c "pg_basebackup --host=MASTER_SERVER_IP  --username=replication --pgdata=/var/lib/postgresql/12/main --wal-method=stream --write-recovery-conf"
```

5. After base backup is done start standby server.

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

To check the progress of replication:

```
psql -U postgres

# On master
select * from pg_stat_replication;

# On standby
select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver;
```

To promote standby server to master mode:

```
psql -U postgres
select pg_promote();
```